# Define quantifier variable issue in forall in Z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

The following code should return sat with z>=15. However, it is giving unsat. I think, the quantifier variable 'y' must be defined within the forall scope. Please suggest how to do that.

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
s.set(auto_config=False, mbqi=False)

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
z = Int('z')

s.add(ForAll([y], Implies(And(y>-5,y<5),And(x==y+z,x>10))))

print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, what you wrote doesn't really mean what you intended. What you wrote picks a single value of `x` to satisfy it. Instead, what you're trying to say is, there's some `x` that can be picked for each value of `y`. So, just state it with that quantification:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
s.set(auto_config=False, mbqi=False)

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
z = Int('z')

s.add(ForAll([y], Implies(And(y>-5,y<5), Exists([x], And(x==y+z,x>10)))))

print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print(m)
```

Note the existential on `x`. This prints:

```
sat
[z = 15]
```

While z3 can solve simple cases like this where quantification is involved, you should be aware that SMT solvers are usually not good at reasoning with quantifiers, especially when they're nested. You might start getting `unknown` as a result once the problem gets complicated enough.